# How to put formula for columns in python pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Input: Table 1

```
Fruit Price_day_1 Price_Day_2 
Apple  45         43             
Orange 53         55
Mango  56         38
```

Expected Output: Table 2

```
 Fruit     Price_day
            _1      Price_Day_2   Difference=(Price_Day_1 - Price_Day_2)
    Apple  45         43             2
    Orange 53         55            -2
    Mango  56         38            18
```

How to put this formula and generate a new column using pandas?

Comment: Please tell us what you already tried, what the results of your research so far were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need subtract columns:

```
df['Difference=(Price_Day_1 - Price_Day_2)'] = df['Price_day_1'] - df['Price_Day_2']
print (df)
    Fruit  Price_day_1  Price_Day_2  Difference=(Price_Day_1 - Price_Day_2)
0   Apple           45           43                                       2
1  Orange           53           55                                      -2
2   Mango           56           38                                      18
```

Each formula has to be rewrite to pandas code.

Comment: this is for calculation part but I need the calculated column to be on the main dataframe

Comment: @YogeshSP - Not sure if understand, can you explain more?

Comment: Yes, I don't want answer for single column instead I want answer for my Expected Output: Table 2

Comment: can you get it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176787/discussion-between-yogesh-s-p-and-jezrael).